# AMPScript to Split copy on two lines

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm looking to see what the ampscript i should use as i want to split copy over two lines i was thinking to use the substring function but i have different lengths

Anytime
day return (anytime on one line and the rest on another line)

and

off peak
day return (anytime on one line and the rest on another line)

any example would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Substring()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Substring), yes.  Or you can use [BuildRowSetFromString()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#BuildRowSetFromString) (with a space delimiter) and iterate through words.

I've also used this script to trim a sentence down to the nearest word based on a max character count:

```
%%[

    var @l, @ln, @cutoffPos, @done, @sentenceTrimmed

    set @ln = length(@sentence)
    set @cutoffPos = length(@sentence)
    set @done = 0
    set @maxLen = 40

    if @ln > @maxLen then

        for @l = @maxLen downto 1 do

          if substring(@sentence,@l,1) == " " and @done == 0 then

             set @cutoffPos = subtract(@l,1)
             set @done = 1

          endif

        next @l

    endif

    set @sentenceTrimmed = substring(@sentence,1,@cutoffPos)

]%%
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem i am having is the length as i have length of ,7,8,19(which i want on the first line) so i don't think the substring would work as i will be pulling through to much data.  I have have split this in the lookup table so its working. thanks for your help

Comment: @PeterHo - dont forget to mark this as answered if its satisfied the need!